# jQuery password strength plugin: Retrieving password's strength

Tags: jquery, grails, passwords

I'm working on a legacy groovy project that uses jQuery's password strength validator [plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/password_strength). It works great. However, a new requirement arrived today, indicating that the form should not be submited if the strength of the password is below `good` (this is an arbitrary value)

Is there any way to achieve this? Possibly via javascript? Ajax solutions are welcome to.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are working with jQuery, the verification WILL be JavaScript

Comment: @Ast, Im hoping so. But can't get it done :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two ways of doing it:

1. Check class of warning, it is something like ".password_strength_1", so strength is in its name.
2. Just edit plugin :) It won't hurt.

Comment: Went with #1. Solution involved using firebug to see the code generated. Then used something like if (($("span.top_goodPass").length == 0  && $("span.top_strongPass").length == 0 )){ //not good enough !}

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may work:

```
$('#myform').submit(function(e) {
    if ($(this).find('.password_strength_1').size() != 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('Your password is too weak!');
    }
});
```

Comment: "your password should be more weekend?"

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I knew something seemed off. I could use another weekend myself, I guess.